# If Web element not found visit web page and login again in Vba-Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've below macro to login web page and exract data from `table`.
But sometimes login is not successful and message appears on webpage - *Please try to login again.*
So I tried adding  `If` loop to check whether `web element` has been loaded and if not try again login. But to due to presence of `If` loop, getting below error:

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Private ch          As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub TestSelenium()

Dim Lastrow As Variant
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim sheetsname As String
Dim tr, td, th As WebElement
Dim c, r, l    As Integer
Lastrow = 1
Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
' ch.AddArgument "--headless"        ''Hide browser
ch.Start
ch.Get "https://address"

ch.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 20000        ' 5 seconds

With ch

    With .FindElementById("logInForm")
        .FindElementById("j_username").SendKeys "name"
        .FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys "password@1012"
        .FindElementById("submitButton", timeout:=1000000).Click
        
        'ch.Timeouts.Server = 120000 ' 2 mins
        'ch.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 50000 ' 5 seconds
    End With
    'Stop '<==  Delete me after inspection
    
   For l = 1 To 5
        If ch.IsElementPresent(FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table")) Then
        
             '' Print header
            For Each tr In ch.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table").FindElementByTag("thead").FindElementsByTag("tr")
                c = 1
                For Each th In tr.FindElementsByTag("th")
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = th.Text
                    c = c + 1
                Next th
                r = r + 1
            Next tr
            '' Print table data
            For Each tr In ch.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
                c = 1
                For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = td.Text
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
                r = r + 1
            Next tr
            
        Else ' if table NOT found
            With .FindElementById("logInForm")
                .FindElementById("j_username").SendKeys "name"
                .FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys "password@1012"
                .FindElementById("submitButton", timeout:=1000000).Click
                
                ch.Timeouts.Server = 120000 ' 2 mins
                ch.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 50000 ' 5 seconds
            End With
            For Each tr In ch.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table").FindElementByTag("thead").FindElementsByTag("tr")
                c = 1
                For Each th In tr.FindElementsByTag("th")
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = th.Text
                    c = c + 1
                Next th
                r = r + 1
            Next tr
            ' Print table data
            For Each tr In ch.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
                c = 1
                For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = td.Text
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
                r = r + 1
            Next tr

        End If
    Next l
    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ch.FindElementByXPath` instead of `FindElementByXPath`

Comment: I could run macro now. But getting `No element error` at line of `If` so I guess, my code in `If` loop is not correct. Don't know why If statement not executing.

Comment: I guess, I would need to kill current page in case of login error and open web page and do all procedure. Any help please.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `For l = 1 to 5` loop? It doesn't appear to be used inside the loop

Comment: Sometimes, login is successful on 2nd or 3rd attempt, so instead of infinite loop, I added `counter` as 5 and used `For` loop.

Comment: Also, getting `Type mismatch` error when login is successful on 1st attempt at `If` statement.

Comment: Without seeing the page in question its hard to offer any suggestions, removing the loop (or at least breaking out of it on success) and the duplicated code would make it easier to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some assumptions, so unlikely that this code will actually work with your target website.

Try to separate your code, make sure you are logged in, and once you are then run your scraping code.

Trying to roll them all together just makes it harder for you.

The idea (untested) below is the "login" aspect.

```
Option Explicit
Private Driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Main()

Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Driver.Start

Driver.Get "url"

If Login(Driver) = False Then
    Debug.Print "failed (multiple times) to login"
Else
    Debug.Print "successful login"
    ' do your stuff here
End If

End Sub

' this assumes that the login form does not exist if successfully logged in
Public Function Login(ByRef Driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver) As Boolean
Static LoginAttempt As Integer
Dim Form As Selenium.WebElement
Set Form = Driver.FindElementById("logInForm", 1000)

If Not Form Is Nothing Then
' the login form exists
    If LoginAttempt > 5 Then
        Debug.Print "login attempt exceeded"
        Login = False
    Else
        LoginAttempt = LoginAttempt + 1
    End If
    Driver.FindElementById("j_username").SendKeys "username"
    Driver.FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys "password"
    Driver.FindElementById("submitButton").Click
    ' assume that clicking login button triggers navigation, so wait a little bit
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:5")
    ' re-run the login and return that result
    Login = Login(Driver)
Else
    LoginAttempt = 0
    Login = True
End If

End Function
```

*Update*

I cant figure out why the `NoSuchElement` error occurs as that method of testing has always worked for me (until now).

The following code works for me

```
Public Function Login(ByRef Driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver) As Boolean
Static LoginAttempt As Integer
Dim By As New Selenium.By

If Driver.IsElementPresent(By.ID("logInForm"), 1000) = True Then
    If LoginAttempt > 5 Then
        Login = False
    Else
        LoginAttempt = LoginAttempt + 1
    End If
    Driver.FindElementById("j_username").SendKeys "username"
    Driver.FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys "password"
    Driver.FindElementById("submit").Click
    ' assume that clicking login button triggers navigation, so wait a little bit
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:5")
    ' run again to test if successful
    Login = Login(Driver)
Else
    LoginAttempt = 0
    Login = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: It seems to be working as I saw 1st login was not successful but 2nd time was and page was loaded as expected. But getting `NoSuchElementError` at `If Not Driver.FindElementById("logInForm", 1000) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: I've made a small change, but don't see why it would make a difference. That error shouldn't occur as its exactly what the code is testing for.

Comment: Same error at line `Set Form = ...` though page is loaded. Before your answer I was about to try whether A1 cell has any content, if not, run whole macro again. Maybe I will utilize your structure there.

Comment: Still some error at my end.

Answer (score 0):

As I was extracting data and writing to excel, added check using `Do Until` loop to iterate through whole macro which works:

```
Option Explicit
Private ch          As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub TestSelenium()

Dim Lastrow As Variant
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim sheetsname As String
Dim tr, td, th As WebElement
Dim c, r, l As Integer
Lastrow = 1
Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do Until i = 6 Or Range("A1") <> 0 ' Check with multiple attempts till A1 cell is not empty

    On Error Resume Next
    ch.AddArgument "--headless"        ''Hide browser
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://address"
    
    ch.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 20000        ' 5 seconds

    With ch
    
        With .FindElementById("logInForm")
            .FindElementById("j_username").SendKeys "username"
            .FindElementById("j_password").SendKeys "password"
            .FindElementById("submitButton", timeout:=1000000).Click
            
            'ch.Timeouts.Server = 120000 ' 2 mins
            'ch.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 50000 ' 5 seconds
        End With
        'Stop '<==  Delete me after inspection
        
                 '' Print header
                For Each tr In ch.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table").FindElementByTag("thead").FindElementsByTag("tr")
                    c = 1
                    For Each th In tr.FindElementsByTag("th")
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = th.Text
                        c = c + 1
                    Next th
                    r = r + 1
                Next tr
                '' Print table data
                For Each tr In ch.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
                    c = 1
                    For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Lastrow + r, c).Value = td.Text
                        c = c + 1
                    Next td
                    r = r + 1
                Next tr
        .Quit
    End With
    
    i = i + 1
    MsgBox "i is " & i
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```